# My mongo database doesn't change the object, but i see the changes in the console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello i have a problem,

this is my code:
I have route:

```
app.get("/add", userController.auth, () => {
    {
        const u = await users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, 
            {$push: {friends: {name: req.body.username} } }    
        )
        console.log(u);
        return res.status(201).json({
            friends: u.friends
        })
    }
}
```

userControllAuth.js:

```
exports.auth = async(req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers["token"];
    const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, "i_put_my_secret_here")
    const UserByToken = await users.findOne({_id: verifyToken.id}).select("-password")
    req.user = UserByToken

    next()

}
```

schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "User Name Must Be Apply!"],
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 15
    },
    friends: [
        {
            name: String
        }
    ]
})
const userModel = mongoose.model("users", userSchema)


module.exports = userModel;
```

i tried to updated the user, when i console the variable "u" i see the changes,
but when i go to the database i dont see any changes.
what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, The changes were made after 10 minutes.
I dont why. good day.